# Requesting Permissions & Permission Group

Tags: java, android, permissions

As per Android Guideline user need grant permission if they have device with android version Marshmallow and up. I have followed instruction given [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/permissions/requesting.html) for my application.
I have declared two permission in my application called WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE and READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE in my manifest file. I am little confused in

> Permission Group

I have asked permission of **WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE**, I still need ask permission **READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE** or it may automatic granted when user grant **WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE** permission ?

Comment: Yes it will grant read permission

Comment: Yes it will grant read permission too if write permission is granted.

Comment: If you provide write permission, read permissions will automatically be granted. To handle runtime permissions easily, you can use my library. https://github.com/nabinbhandari/Android-Permissions